# Using pointers and references, can't figure out why DFS is recurring infinitely

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a simple DFS on a directed graph using homemade data structures (HashMap and LinkedList) to learn C++, but for some reason the DFS method is infinitely recurring.

I think it's infinitely recurring because for some reason the nodes stored in the hashmap (the graph) are not actually being marked visited during the DFS.  I thought I understood pointers and references but apparently I do not. I would appreciate it if someone could help me see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the infinitely recurring DFS method:

```
template <class T>
bool Graph<T>::DFS(const T& v1, const T& v2) {
    if(v1 == v2)
        return true;

    Graph<T>::Node * node = *(map->find(v1));
    node->visited = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < node->adjacent->size(); i++) 
        if(node->adjacent->get(i).visited == false) 
            return DFS(node->adjacent->get(i).data, v2);

    return false;
}
```

Here's the HashMap class find() method

```
template <class K, class V>
V* HashMap<K, V>::find(const K& key) const {
    int bucket = (int) hash_fn(key) % arrLength;

    HashMap<K, V>::Node * temp = buckets[bucket];
    while(temp != NULL && temp->key != key)
        temp = temp->next;
    if(temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
        return &(temp->value);
}
```

Here's the Graph class

```
template <class T>
class Graph {
    struct Node {
        T data;
        bool visited;
        LinkedList<Node> * adjacent;
        Node() {
            adjacent = nullptr;
            visited = false;
        }
        Node(T data) {
            this->data = data;
            adjacent = new LinkedList<Node>();
            visited = false;
        }
    };
    public:
        Graph();
        ~Graph();
        void addEdge(const T& v1, const T& v2);
        bool DFS(const T& v1, const T& v2);

    private:
        HashMap<T, Graph<T>::Node*> * map;
};

template <class T>
Graph<T>::Graph() {
    map = new HashMap<T, Graph<T>::Node*>();
}

template <class T>
Graph<T>::~Graph() {
    map->~Map<T, Graph<T>::Node*>();
}

template <class T>                                  // directed graph
void Graph<T>::addEdge(const T& v1, const T& v2) {  // add edge from v1 to v2

    if(map->find(v1) == NULL)   
        map->insert(v1, new Graph<T>::Node(v1));
    if(map->find(v2) == NULL)
        map->insert(v2, new Graph<T>::Node(v2));

    (*map->find(v1))->adjacent->append( **map->find(v2) ); // oh god
}
```

Here's the Main method where I construct and populate the graph, and then call the DFS method.

```
int main() {

    Graph<int> * graph1 = new Graph<int>(); 
    graph1->addEdge(1, 5);
    graph1->addEdge(5, 9);
    graph1->addEdge(9, 20);

    graph1->DFS(1, 20);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or insight.
-Bob

Comment: `HashMap<T, Graph<T>::Node*>` This looks super weird to me, you would be better off having `HashMap<T, Graph<T>::Node>` and have HashMap add the pointer qualifier where it makes sense.

Comment: also: `map->~Map<T, Graph<T>::Node*>();` This looks like pure evil, and a guaranteed memory leak. Any reason not to just call `delete map;`?

Comment: And more related to your actual question: `LinkedList<Node>` I don't know how that template is implemented, but if it's anything like standard containers, this will create copies of graph inside of each edge reference instead of refering to nodes, resulting in a massive DAG that might look like it's infinitely large if you suspend execution after a while .This is a case wherre `LinkedList<Node*>` would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @Frank Thank you, I changed `LinkedList<Node>` to `LinkedList<Node*>` and that fixed it. But to be honest I don't understand why that fixed it.

Comment: @Frank I didn't want to just call `delete map` because I thought I need to call the destructor to delete all of the Nodes in the adjacency list.

Comment: `delete` calls the destructor and frees the memory. All you are doing is skipping the second step. You are correct tha something needs to destroy these nodes, but that's not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything your use of pointers looks almost random and arbitrary. You have pointers where they don't make sense: `HashMap<T, Graph<T>::Node*>`, and lack of pointers where there should be: `LinkedList<Node> * adjacent`.

You also use dynamic allocation in places that make no sense, like the afformentioned `adjacent` member of `Node`, and your cleanup is either non-existent (`Graph::Node` has no destructor, when it should have one), or completely broken (`Graph<T>::~Graph()` will lead to a guaranteed memory leak).

Furthermore, nothing ever cleans up your `visited` flag, so only one call to DFS will ever work.

Bluntly put, there are a LOT of problem with your code, both design-wise, and implementation-wise.

Your specific DFS issue probably comes from using `LinkedList<Node>` instead of `LinkedList<Node*>` for the adjency list, because that likely causes the graph to become a massive DAG with subgraphs copied into the adjency list, but it's hard to tell without knowing how `LinkedList<>` is implemented.

**Edit** I feel kinda bad for just bluntly saying "this is bad accross the board", here's how I'd implement your code correctly (using the stl instead of your custom containers):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Graph {
  struct Node {
    T data;
    bool visited;
    std::vector<Node*> adjacent;

    Node(T const& d) : data(d), visited(false) {}
  };
public:
  inline void addEdge(T const& v1, T const& v2);
  inline bool DFS(T const& v1, T const& v2);

private:
  inline bool DFS_recur(T const& v1, T const& v2);
  std::unordered_map<T, Node> map;
};

template<typename T>
void Graph<T>::addEdge(T const& v1, T const& v2) {
  auto v1_found = map.emplace(v1, v1).first;
  auto v2_found = map.emplace(v2, v2).first;

  v1_found->second.adjacent.emplace_back(&v2_found->second);
}

template<typename T>
bool Graph<T>::DFS(T const& v1, T const& v2) {
  auto result = DFS_recur(v1, v2);

  // Return to the invariant state.
  for(auto & n : map) {
    n.second.visited = false;
  }
  return result;
}

template<typename T>
bool Graph<T>::DFS_recur(T const& v1, T const& v2) {
  if(v1 == v2) return true;

  auto v1_found = map.find(v1);
  // If v1 is not in the map, we'll be in trouble.
  if(v1_found == map.end()) return false;

  v1_found->second.visited = true;

  for(auto const & neighbour : v1_found->second.adjacent) {
    if(!neighbour->visited) {
      return DFS_recur(neighbour->data, v2);
    }
  }

  return false;
}

int main() {

    Graph<int> graph1;
    graph1.addEdge(1, 5);
    graph1.addEdge(5, 9);
    graph1.addEdge(9, 20);

    graph1.DFS(1, 20);

    return 0;
}
```

Notice how all the memory management is handled through RAII, not a `new` or `delete` in sight.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thanks a lot for your insight. I wasn't thinking at all about why and where to use pointers, I just used them for no particular reason. I'll now try to be more aware of when and where I use pointers and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: static allocation is a completely different thing. I think you mean allocating using value semantics, in which case yes in general, unless you are dealing with polymorphism or shared ownership. Remember that datastructures like `vector` or `map` will allocate their content in the heap, so the containers themselves are actually really small. Adding a level of indirection only serves to make the code harder to read, slower to execute, and more error-prone.